# Add static html files to search API

Tags: google-app-engine, search

I am setting up a site that will host a large amount of static html files, and I want then to be searchable using google app engines search API. 
I have seen plenty of examples on how to host a static website using google app engine, but none that include an example on how to implement searching.

How would I go about setting this up? What is the best way of adding static html files to be searched? Is there a way of doing this en masse, or do I need to crawl through all the files to add them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-cooked/shortcut solution that would take advantage of the fact that the searcheable documents are static files served by your app.

From [Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/#Python_Overview):

> The Search API is based on four main concepts: documents, indexes,
>   queries, and results.

You will need to:

- create a search API document corresponding to each of your static file to be searcheable. Only you can specify at this step how the content of the static file is to be interpreted and translated into the searcheable fields. From [Creating a document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/#Python_Creating_a_document):

> The following code sample shows how to create a document object. The
>   Document constructor is called with the fields argument set to a list
>   of field objects. Each object in the list is created and initialized
>   by using the constructor function of the field's class. Note the use
>   of the [`GeoPoint`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/geopointclass) constructor and the Python `datetime` class to
>   create the appropriate types of field values.
>
> **appengine/standard/search/snippets/snippets.py** [View on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/search/snippets/snippets.py)
>
> ```
> def create_document():
>     document = search.Document(
>         # Setting the doc_id is optional. If omitted, the search service will
>         # create an identifier.
>         doc_id='PA6-5000',
>         fields=[
>             search.TextField(name='customer', value='Joe Jackson'),
>             search.HtmlField(
>                 name='comment', value='this is <em>marked up</em> text'),
>             search.NumberField(name='number_of_visits', value=7),
>             search.DateField(name='last_visit', value=datetime.now()),
>             search.DateField(
>                 name='birthday', value=datetime(year=1960, month=6, day=19)),
>             search.GeoField(
>                 name='home_location', value=search.GeoPoint(37.619, -122.37))
>         ])
>     return document
> ```

- insert the document into the index. Only you know which index should be used for the doc corresponding to each static file. From [Putting documents in an index](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/#Python_Putting_documents_in_an_index):

> When you put a document into an index, the document is copied to
>   persistent storage and each of its fields is indexed according to its
>   name, type, and the `doc_id`.
>
> The following code example shows how to access an Index and put a
>   document into it.
>
> **appengine/standard/search/snippets/snippets.py** [View on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/search/snippets/snippets.py)
>
> ```
> def add_document_to_index(document):
>     index = search.Index('products')
>     index.put(document)
> ```

- provide the app code for performing the searches and processing/displaying the results. Again, only you know what indexes are to be searched and how would the results processed. From [Searching for documents by their contents](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/#Python_Searching_for_documents_by_their_contents):

> To retrieve documents from an index, you construct a query string and
>   call `Index.search()`. The query string can be passed directly as the
>   argument, or you can include the string in a [Query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/queryclass) object which
>   is passed as the argument. By default, `search()` returns matching
>   documents sorted in order of decreasing rank. To control how many
>   documents are returned, how they are sorted, or add computed fields to
>   the results, you need to use a `Query` object, which contains a query
>   string and can also specify other search and sorting options.
>
> **appengine/standard/search/snippets/snippets.py** [View on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/search/snippets/snippets.py)
>
> ```
> def query_index():
>     index = search.Index('products')
>     query_string = 'product: piano AND price < 5000'
>
>     results = index.search(query_string)
>
>     for scored_document in results:
>         print(scored_document)
> ```

**Side note**: if you're actually bundling the static files with your app code (as opposed to serving them from GCS) you need to make the files accessible to your app code. See the **application_readable** row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table:

> **application_readable**
>
> Optional. Boolean. By default, files declared in static file handlers
>   are uploaded as static data and are only served to end users. They
>   cannot be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the
>   files are also uploaded as code data so your application can read
>   them. Both uploads are charged against your code and static data
>   storage [resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Code).

Comment: The part of this I'm struggling with is creating the documents that correspond to the static html files. If I want to be able to do a full text search of the html file, do I need to create a html field for the document and copy the text content of the html file into the value of this field? or is there some way to add the html file itself as a searchable field?